# Not all Linux SMB shares are accessible from Windows

Tags: linux, windows, networking, network-shares, samba

I have two problems with accessing SMB shares from Windows (Windows Server 2022).

On my Linux server (EuroLinux RHEL) I installed an SMB server and got it working.

At first I had only one share (\share) and it worked and still works.

Then I wanted to use a second drive as a second share. So I mounted the /home/vault drive and set up the samba share. In Windows, this share shows up, but when I try to access it, the error message "[the network name cannot be found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BLXOo.png)" appears (even when I try to mount it using the net use command)

So I thought it might be a problem with the mounted drive and wanted to use a third shared folder (/test).
I set up the third share just like the first, but now Windows says [You do not have permissions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eaKjt.png)

All shared folders have the same permission and the same configuration

```
chown guest <folder> && chmod 777 <folder> -R
```

My samba config

```
[root@lx-host home]# cat /etc/samba/smb.conf
[global]
    workgroup = WORKGROUP
    netbios name = lx-host
    server string = lx-host
    server role = standalone server
    passdb backend = tdbsam
    security = user
    guest account = guest
    map to guest = Bad Password

[test]
    path = /home/test
    writable = yes
    public = yes
    printable = no

[vault]
    path = /home/vault
    writable = yes
    public = yes
    printable = no

[share]
    path = /home/share
    writable = yes
    public = yes
    printable = no
```

My folder permissions

```
[root@lx-host home]# exa
drwxrwxrwx@ - guest 15 Oct 18:58 guest
drwxr-xr-x@ - root  28 Oct 12:07 iso
drwxr-xr-x@ - root   9 Nov 09:33 prog
drwxrwxrwx@ - guest  9 Nov 02:57 share
drwxrwxrwx@ - guest 11 Nov 11:04 test
drwSrwSrwx  - guest 11 Nov 10:47 vault
drwxr-xr-x@ - root  26 Oct 14:46 vm

[root@lx-host home]# ls -l
total 4
drwxrwxrwx. 2 guest guest   62 Oct 15 18:58 guest
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root  root   170 Oct 28 12:07 iso
drwxr-xr-x. 4 root  root    39 Nov  9 09:33 prog
drwxrwxrwx. 6 guest root    57 Nov  9 02:57 share
drwxrwxrwx. 3 guest root    18 Nov 11 12:02 test
drwSrwSrwx. 3 guest root  4096 Nov 11 10:47 vault
drwxr-xr-x. 4 root  root   155 Oct 26 14:46 vm
```

Access from linux to smb

```
[root@lx-host home]# smbclient -L //lx-host -U guest
Password for [WORKGROUP\guest]:

    Sharename       Type      Comment
    ---------       ----      -------
    test            Disk      
    vault           Disk      
    share           Disk      
    IPC$            IPC       IPC Service (lx-host)
```

[all shares seen by Windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ibOo1.png)
[access to the shared folder /share works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5cW7Z.png)

Comment: [Please post your data as text, not image.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/372239)

Comment: thx for the tip. changed it

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the first problem with the mounted drive!!
Because im using Eurolinux based on RHEL it uses SELinux additional security restrictions.
So i need to mount the drive in an other context

```
 /home/vault ext4 defaults,errors=remount-ro,context="system_u:object_r:samba_share_t:s0" 0 1
```

https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/391677

Answer (score 0):

Okay, i gave up looking for a 'great' solution and stuck with this 'ok'
solution:

```
[global]
        create mask = 777
        force create mode = 777
        security mask = 777
        force security mode = 777
[vault]
        directory mask = 2777
        force directory mode = 2777
        directory security mask = 2777
        force directory security mode = 2777
```

For security reasons, this is not ideal, but with my LAN and the special access to it, it is fine for me.